# UIPageViewController with 4 direction scrolling

Tags: ios, customization, uipageviewcontroller

I have created a grid view with the some images on `UIView`, which should like default `iOS Photos app Collection [Screenshot attached]`
[image: CustomGridView]

When clicking on an image, it should show the full image in a screen with UIPageViewController
i added the FullImages with UIPageViewController but it is only two directional, i can only scroll from left to right and right to left OR top to bottom and bottom to top, But i want to do both at a time

for example:
I have 9 images in the following order

```
1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9
```

suppose i'm at image `5`

if i scroll from `top to bottom` i have to go to image `2`

now, if i scroll from `bottom to top` i have to go to image `5`

now if i scroll again from `bottom to top` i have to go to image `8`

now if i scroll from `right to left` i have to go to image `9`

now if i scroll from `top to bottom` i have to go to image `6`

now if i scroll from `left to right` i have to go to image `5`

can somebody suggest how to achieve this?

can i use the `UIPageViewController` or any other control to get this effect

Comment: have a look on UICollectionView (high-level) or UIScrollView (low-level).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `UICollectionView` for `Grid layout` for photos.

You can't set `both dimension scrollability` of collection view. But you will achieve this by using Multiple Section

As an example :

I think you need something like this.. Just remove First Row & Columns. & add ImageView instead of Just Text..

http://www.brightec.co.uk/ideas/uicollectionview-using-horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling-sticky-rows-and-columns

[image: Grid Layout]

Another good eg is: https://github.com/izotx/ScrollableCollectionView

& if you want to load view at the `middle` photo of grid then set `ContentOffset` of that collectionview accordingly..

As far as i understand your problem, this solution should work in your problem..

Try this out & inform me if you solve it or not. Or you get another best solution..

Comment: The second one you have given using CollectionView on a ScrollView it is not suitable for my problem, can you please provide me any example project for the first given solution http://www.brightec.co.uk/ideas/uicollectionview-using-horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling-sticky-rows-and-columns

Comment: sorry to be late, Here is your source example project.. https://github.com/brightec/CustomCollectionViewLayout

Answer (score 1):

A `UIPageViewController` will not do what you want. Think of it like a book. That's what it offers. It won't offer scrolling through a grid of pages like that.

A customized `UICollectionView` is probably the best starting point for what you want.

Comment: Can you explain more how can i achieve this with the `UICollectionView`, thanks

Comment: I suggest searching online on "UICollectionView grid layout". It will take some fine-tuning to make a tile from your collection view fill the whole screen and snap to the screen like you want.